# C# reading html attribute value using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
str = "<img src='http://server/path/a.jpg' />blah blah blah blah";
```

What would be the regular expression to find the attribute source value?

I do not want to use HTML Agility pack.

Regards,

Comment: Why don't you want to use the HTML agility pack

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to get an attribute from HTML tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079423/regular-expression-to-get-an-attribute-from-html-tag)

Comment: regex seems pretty useless as <img src never changes... just remove everything around it

Comment: HTML is not a regular language.  **do not use regular expressions to parse HTML!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: actually this is only one time parsing.. need to fix an ETL routine; otherwise, I know all issues with regex vs HTML :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use HTML agility pack; even for small things!

:: sigh ::

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use regex to parse HTML**. Use one of the many available parsers that suits your needs.

But if you really have to, for that sting this simple (and in many cases broken) regex could work for you:

`\bsrc\s*=\s*["']([^"'>]+)`

Comment: thanks for the quick response; but I believe agility pack will help me out!